# Why my render method is react called twice

Tags: reactjs

[image]I am quite new to react and redux. This is a little confusing problem for me. Can someone please explain this why my searchTerm state value printed twice (render method is getting called twice) after every input change. I read react and learnt that on every state change, render is called but in this called render is called twice? Am I getting this wrong?

## App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Todos from './components/Todos';
import Header from './components/Header';

class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    searchTerm : '',
    todos: [{
    id: 1,
    completed: true,
    text: "I am number one"
    }, 
{
    id: 2,
    completed: false,
    text: "I am number two"
},
{
    id: 3,
    completed: false,
    text: "I am number three"
}]
}

markComplete = (id) => {
    this.setState({
    todos: this.state.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed;
        }
        return todo;
    })
    });
}

deleteTo = (id) => {
    this.setState({
    todos: [...this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id!==id)]
    });
}

search = (evt) => {
    const value = evt.target.value;
    this.setState({
    searchTerm: value
    });
}

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <Header />
        { console.log(this.state.searchTerm) }
        <input type="text" onChange = {this.search} />         
        <Todos todos = {this.state.todos} markComplete = {this.markComplete} deleteTo = {this.deleteTo}/>
    </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

## Todos.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

class Todos extends Component {

render() {
    return this.props.todos.map((todo) => 
    <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo = {todo} markComplete = {this.props.markComplete} deleteTo={this.props.deleteTo}/>)
}
}

export default Todos;
```

## TodoItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TodoItem extends Component {

getStyle = () => {
    return { textDecoration: this.props.todo.completed ? "line-through": "none" };
};

getButtonStyle = () => {
    return {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        border: 'none',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        float: 'right',
        padding: '5px 10px',
        borderRadius: '50%'
    };
}

render() {
    const {id, text} = this.props.todo;

    return ( 
    <div style={this.getStyle()}>
        <p>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange= { () => this.props.markComplete(id) }/> {' '}
        {text} 
        <button style={this.getButtonStyle()} onClick = { () => this.props.deleteTo(id)}> x </button>
        </p>
    </div>
    );
}
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Comment: I've tested your code here: https://playcode.io/591823/. I found that the render just called once on state change. I think nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: If I change input text field, it print value twice on console. @fxbayuanggara

Comment: I have also attached picture. Please have a look

Comment: Just wild guessing, try to change the search function with this one:

 `search = evt => {
    const value = evt.target.value
    this.setState({ ...this.state, searchTerm: value })
  }`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

it's probably because of React **StrictMode** in your *index.js* file (if you use create-react-app).

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

strict mode checks for potential problems and caused to run some lifecycle methods twice (like constructor, render, componentShouldUpdate, etc).

> Strict mode checks are run in development mode only; they do not impact the production build.

you can read more about it on [strict-mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode)

Comment: OMG. You were right and how can I avoid this?

Comment: You are right. One thing I  noticed is , in Chrome render gets called one time with or without strict mode. But in Edge with strict mode it gets called twice and one time without strict mode.

Comment: Great definitive answer.  so glad someone explained this clearly because I couldn't tell if I had code that was causing render() to fire twice for some reason.  I commented the strictmode out and instantly saw it was only called once so I replaced it in dev.  Thanks again. 

Answer (score 5):

The `render` function can be called almost any number of times before the commit phase occurs and updates are flushed to the DOM. The render function should also be a pure function, meaning there are no side-effects, like console logging. Instead use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function to log when state or props update. Perhaps this diagram would help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to avoid the side effects is to not assign **Dynamic values** in the **Render()**, just **keep it in the state**, and call it before the Render() as example on Click() method.