# Function in the component is getting called twice in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using **useMemo** react hook in the function component.
I am not sure why the console log is getting twice printed. Here below is my code:

```
import './App.css';
import react,{useState,useMemo} from 'react';

function App() {

  const [count,setCount] = useState(0);
  const [item,setItem] = useState(10);

  const multiCountMemo = useMemo(function multiCount() {
    console.log("to check if getting inside the function")  <---- this is getting printed twice by default on load app page.
    return count * 5
  },[count])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>useMemo Hook Usage</h1>

      <h2>Count : {count}</h2>
      
      <h2>Item : {item}</h2>

      <h2>{multiCountMemo}</h2>

      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Update Count</button>
      
      <button onClick={() => setItem(item * 10)}>Update Item</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my render method is react called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532410/why-my-render-method-is-react-called-twice)

Comment: which react version are you on?

Comment: I am using "react": "^18.1.0",

Answer (score 3):

This is due to strict mode – check the docs [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode).

`useEffect` in React version 18 causes the component to unmount and mount again after it mounts the first time.
This is why the `console.log` is triggering twice.

note that this only happens in development mode and not production
[image: react docs showing strict mode]