# React component running twice

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a simple To\Do app with react and the homepage is a list of notes that are saved in dummy_data.js as json objects. when I try to console.log something in component **NotesList**, it prints twice in the console. And it is not intended to happen. Running once is required.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import NotesList from './pages/NotesListPage';
import Note from './pages/NotePage';
import Header from './components/Header';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Routes,
    Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Router>
                <Header />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<NotesList />} />
                    <Route path='/note/:id' element={<Note />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

NotesListPage.js

```
import notes from '../assets/dummy_data';
import ListItem from '../components/ListItem';

function NotesList(){
    console.log('am i running twice?')
    return(
        <div>
            {
                notes.map((note, index) =>(
                    <div key={index}>
                        <ListItem note={note} />  
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                ))
               

            }
               
        </div>
    );
}
export default NotesList;
```

ListItem.js

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function ListItem(props){
    //console.log(props)
    return(
        <Link to={`/note/${props.note.id}`}>
            <i>{props.note.body}</i>
        </Link>
    )
}

export default ListItem;
```

dummy_data.js

```
let notes = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "body": "Todays Agenda\n\n- Walk Dog\n- Feed fish\n- Play basketball\n- Eat a salad",
        "updated": "2021-07-14T13:49:02.078653Z",
        "created": "2021-07-13T21:54:16.235392Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "body": "Bob from bar down the \n\n- Take out trash\n- Eat food",
        "updated": "2021-07-13T20:43:18.550058Z",
        "created": "2021-07-13T00:17:13.289897Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "body": "Wash car",
        "updated": "2021-07-13T19:46:12.187306Z",
        "created": "2021-07-13T00:16:22.399841Z"
    }
]


export default notes;
```

when I try to do console.log(props) in **ListItem**, same thing happens. Can someone tell me what could be the reason for that?

Comment: Are you using <StrictMode> in your index.js? Sometimes your components renders twice to debug them in development mode. Try removing it for a moment and try again

Comment: There's nothing in your code that's rendering the component twice.  There are [other answers on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532410/why-my-render-method-is-react-called-twice) that discuss why this can happen, including @SlothOverlord's suggestion above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this behavior might be because **StrictMode** whitch renders `components twice` (on dev but not production) in order to detect any problems with your code and warn you about them (which can be quite useful).

if you don't want it to do so you can disable StrictMode by removing the `<React.StrictMode>` tag in the `index.js` :

**change  :**

```
ReactDOM.render(
     <React.StrictMode>
       <app/>
     </React.StrictMode>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

**to** :

```
ReactDOM.render(
     
       <app/>     , 
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```