# React getDerivedStateFromProps is being called 2 times

Tags: reactjs

I am having a very simple question, I am having a very simple react with 2 files: App.js and Header.js.

Here I am sharing my code in [CodeSandBox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-bird-nln0ny?file=/src/App.js:130-156).

My question is that since `getDerivedStateFromProps` only gets called when the component is being mounted, why would it be called 2 times ? checking the console, props and state are being displayed 2 times.

Comment: I believe it is due to the use of StrictMode. Have a look here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532410/why-my-render-method-is-react-called-twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532410/why-my-render-method-is-react-called-twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no problems in your code, this is happening because of `StrictMode` and that's normal.

> Strict Mode only runs in development, which does not impede the production build. It logs extra warnings or errors and invokes functions **twice** to ensure that the expected results always occur

you can verify:

```
root.render(
    <App />
);
```

**NOTE : This is not recommaended**